# Angular2 access to the methods in child component from parent

Tags: methods, angular, components, parent, children

My question is about the way of have access to childerns component methods from parent component. I found solution which is describe using below example, but I afraid that may be I do it in wrong, not 'angular2 right' way.

For instance we have child:

```
@Component({ ... })
export class Modal {
    ...
    open() {
        ...
    }
}
```

And parent:

```
import { Modal } from '../common';
...
@Component({
  selector: 'editor',
  directives: [ Modal ],
  templateUrl: './editor.html',
  ...
})
export class Editor {

    _modal = null;

    ...

    bindModal(modal) { this._modal=modal; }

    open() {
        this._modal.open();
    }
}
```

And in editor.html:

```
<button (click)="open()">Open Editor</button>

<modal #editModal>{{ bindModal(editModal) }}
    Here is my editor body in modal (popup) window
    ...
</modal>
```

This is solution for have access from Editor component to the `open()` method inside Modal component. It is a little bit tricky. The question is: is there a simplest and more direct way without using 'bindModal' method?

Comment: there are many ways to do it.

Comment: `@ViewChild` decorator is explained [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-calls-a-viewchild-)

Comment: To get access to many instances use [@ViewChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to do it,

## **@ViewChild**

```
import  {ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { Modal } from '../common';
...
@Component({
  selector: 'editor',
  directives: [ Modal ],
  templateUrl: './editor.html',
  ...
})
export class Editor {
 @ViewChild(Modal) md:Modal;

 Open()
 {
    this.md.open();
 }

}
```

Other way is to use [**#localVariable**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child-local-var) and from parent itself you can access child methods.

Comment: Ok, but tell me, what if in editor.html i have more that one modal? For instance <modal #editModalOne>..</modal> <modal #editModalTwo>..</modal> ? The solution describet in my question will works (but we must implement bindModal2 method)

Comment: Then, you can use #LocalVariable, check link given answer or other than that you can use `exportAs`.

Comment: In fact, in example in question i use #LocalVariable - so in case of multiple modal, the solution in question is right way (ofcourse we need implement bindModal2 or bindModal(editModalOne,'modalOne') and put in in _modals =  { modalOne : editModalOne, modalTwo: editModalTwo } etc.